# Get response status with UrlConnection using setIfModifiedSince

Tags: java, urlconnection

`UrlConnection` supports methods `setIfModifiedSince` and `getLastModified`. But I don't understand how can I tell whether resource was modified or not. If I use `HttpUrlConnection`, I can inspect `responseCode`, but `UrlConnection` does not have that property.

I can see that `UrlConnection` returns an empty stream if resource was not modified. But it's not clear how can I tell a difference between use-cases when resource was modified to empty and resource was not modified.

Comment: Are you using `UrlConnection` only for HTTP(S)-URLs or fir URLs with other protocols. too?

Comment: It's more about code design and avoiding unnecessary downcasts. Right now I'm using http connection and downcast to HttpUrlConnection but I don't like it.